# When should I start planning for the next version?

Tags: planning

My company is setting dates for planning the version on the first day of the version.

To me it seems to be waaaay too late.. I think it should be at least a couple of weeks before that.

When should we start the planning process? Is there a standard for this process and how it should be handled?

Answer (score 1):

### Planning Within the Project Schedule

There's nothing wrong with putting most of your planning processes inside your project schedule. In fact, planning is a necessary part of most work packages, so *scheduling* your planning activities within the overall project plan can make a lot of sense.

### Planning Lead Time Can Vary

As for when you should start planning, I don't believe there's a canonical answer to this; a lot depends on your chosen project management framework. For example, frameworks that require a lot of up-front planning and design (e.g. WaterFailure™) will likely require a great deal more lead time for planning than agile frameworks (e.g. Scrum or Kanban) that make use of "just enough" or "just-in-time" planning at the start of each iteration or milestone.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard process for this, only recommendations: it is a good practice to start planning as early as possible until it is clear to everybody that a **plan is not a commitment**.

If I were you, I would follow the *1/3 rule*: plan the first 1/3 very detailed on the task level, plan the second 1/3 on the user story level, and finally plan the last 1/3 on the epic level.

With this approach you can have an idea **when you might finished the project**, and **what are your next steps**. With this information you can go to your boss or supervisor and see whether this is fine with him or her and **talk about risks**. If you can do this before the start you can eliminate problems before even officially starting the project.

After a several days or weeks, you do you planning again using the information from the past days/weeks, but this time user stories might become tasks, and epics might become user stories etc.